Get the largest rectangle possible when the corners of the rectangle are cut
So we have a rectangle with, let's say dimensions of 120ft length, 72ft breadth and 20mm thickness (we assume thickness is negligible thus consider this cuboid a 2D rectangle). I want to use JavaScript to make a function, such that if any rectangular regions are cut from the corners of this rectangle, I can still find the largest possible rectangle inside the new shape. And that rectangle will always be at 90deg.
Here's my approach but it's wrong
class Rectangle {
        length: number;
        breadth: number;
        thickness: number;
        area: number;

        constructor(length: number, breadth: number, thickness: number) {
            this.length = length;
            this.breadth = breadth;
            this.thickness = thickness;
            this.area = length * breadth;
        }
    }

    const calculateUsableDimensions = (
        deductions: IDefectWidgetContent['deductions'],
        defaultDimensions: IDefectWidgetContent['defaultDimensions']
    ): Rectangle => {
        const { length: defaultLength, breadth: defaultBreadth, thickness } = defaultDimensions;

        deductions.sort(
            (a, b) => Number(b.length) * Number(b.breadth) - Number(a.length) * Number(a.breadth)
        );

        let lengthSide = 0;
        let breadthSide = 0;

        for (const deduction of deductions) {
            const { corner, length: deductionLength, breadth: deductionBreadth, thickness } = deduction;

            if (corner === 'A' || corner === 'B') {
                lengthSide += Number(deductionLength);
            } else {
                breadthSide += Number(deductionBreadth);
            }
        }

        const remainingLength = Number(defaultLength) - lengthSide;
        const remainingBreadth = Number(defaultBreadth) - breadthSide;

        return new Rectangle(remainingLength, remainingBreadth, 20); // Thickness is set to 20
    };

Here is the playground for this Playground | StoneTEKK Defects Visualizer 
This is what a data of dimensions and deductions looks like
deductions: [
               { corner: 'A', length: 'l', breadth: 'b', thickness: '20' },
               { corner: 'B', length: 'l', breadth: 'b', thickness: '20' },
               { corner: 'C', length: 'l', breadth: 'b', thickness: '20' },
               { corner: 'D', length: 'l', breadth: 'b', thickness: '20' }
            ],
defaultDimensions: { length: '120', breadth: '72', thickness: '20' },

Assume all datatypes in int/Number. Also the visualizer gives accurate representation of the cut-outs. Only it does not calculate the cut-outs correctly and fail to subtract the deductions in a way it can take care of overlaps, and making the available biggest rectangle.

Update
Let's take a look at this example

Because of these cuts, we will need to make the largest possible rectangle, and it will be smaller rectangle than 120 * 72,
Now if applying brute force, multiple rectangles are possible, I will showcase 2.


Their areas are 7080 sqft and 7684 sqft. So answer is to return
{ length : 113, breadth: 68, thickness: 20} 

Remember thickness will always remain 20 as we assume for 2D while solving this.

will there always be deductions for each corner?

Please provide the expected output for a concrete example where your current code does not return what you expect.

@Yogi It will always be a rectangle , so if there are smaller rectangles / chips that get deducted, that particular new shape can have 4-12 vertices, (12 when all 4 sides have a deduction), and we need the biggest rectangle possible from that shape

@johnSmith No there won't always be a deduction, we can have no deductions ( just 4 vertices), or just deduction on one corner (6 vertices). -- to 12 vertices max

I will update this question with example and answer @trincot

I have added an example with the answer and reasoning

Assuming there are two possible rectangles to cutout (horizontal or vertical) and you want to find out the biggest possible.
Here is some pseudocode that should calculate the size of the vertical rectangle correctly (i use slightly different structure of deductions so you dont have to iterate it and easier readability, should be easy to transform into that):
vert_length = length - (Math.max(deductions.A.l, deductions.D.l) + Math.max(deductions.B.l, deductions.C.l));
vert_size = vert_length * breadth;

You would have to calculate the horizontal rectangle the same way and then compare
Update:  i made a codesnippet analogue to IT goldmans answer, i get different result, which ones are correct might depend on what your desired result is...


function findBiggestRectangle(defaultDimensions, deductions) {
  const { length, breadth, thickness } = defaultDimensions;

  // for quick reference
  const corners = deductions.reduce(function(agg, item) {
    agg[item.corner] = item
    return agg
  }, {})

  var vert_length = length - (Math.max(corners.A.length, corners.D.length) + Math.max(corners.B.length, corners.C.length));
  var vert_size = vert_length * breadth;
  
  var hor_breadth = breadth - (Math.max(corners.A.breadth, corners.D.breadth) + Math.max(corners.B.breadth, corners.C.breadth));
  var hor_size = length * hor_breadth;
  var horizontal = hor_size >= vert_size;
  return {
    size: horizontal ? hor_size : vert_size,
    length: horizontal ? length : vert_length,
    breadth: horizontal ? hor_breadth : breadth,
  }
}

// Test data
const defaultDimensions = { length: '120', breadth: '72', thickness: '20' }
const deductions = [
  { corner: 'A', length: '30', breadth: '20', thickness: '20'},
  { corner: 'B', length: '40', breadth: '10', thickness: '20'},
  { corner: 'C', length: '20', breadth: '30', thickness: '20'},
  { corner: 'D', length: '30', breadth: '30', thickness: '20'}
]

console.log (findBiggestRectangle(defaultDimensions, deductions))




I don't think we need an orientation, see the labels "l" and "b" , the "l" labels are always along the length and "b" are always along the breadth.

Check my updated question (I have added an example and please see https://www.stonetekk.in/defect), thanks!

okay, now i understand, yes my code makes a way more simple assumption so this is not the answer ;)

(my assumption was that the rectangle needs to have either full length or breadth)

If the center rectangle is as big as possible, then each of its sides must butt up against one of the edges in the problem (otherwise you could move that side to make the rectangle bigger) -- the horizontal sides butt against horizontal edges and the vertical sides butt up against vertical edges.
In the problem, there are 6 horizontal edges and 6 vertical edges.  Just test all the combinations.  Of all the rectangles you find that fit, remember the biggest one.

I didn't say "vertices"

Sorry for the confusion

@YashRajBharti: Note that when you tag a post "algorithm", a reasonably precise description of the algorithm is a perfectly legitimate answer.  I saw the problem, spent a few minutes, and came up with the same conclusion as Matt.  I was going to write up an answer and hadn't decided whether or not I would include code, but then I saw that Matt had already provided an equivalent answer.  And I couldn't tell if it was homework, so I chose not to write any code.  This shouldn't be difficult.

@ScottSauyet Thank you, I have solved it, it isn't a "homework", It's a client project.
